# Bigquery table Mk command not working -- schema error

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I tried

```
 bq mk -t \
> --schema schema.json \
> --time_partitioning_field flight_date data_analysis.flight_delays_json_partitioned
```

BigQuery error in mk operation:

> Invalid field name "schema.json". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore,
> and be at most 300 characters long.

[image: Cloud Shell]

Comment: I was able to replicate your error when I specified a `schema.json` **that does not exist in my present working directory**. Please check if your `schema.json` is existing in your present working directory.

Comment: Is this issue resolved yet? Entire tour schema.json is correct with proper format. Also I used below command to create table and it worked for me “bq mk --table <project.dataset.table>
/home/radhika_sharma/table.json”. I haven’t added other details like partitioning and stuff but this command created a table for me. Would you mind providing your json. Is it too big to be pasted here.

Comment: hello radhika can you email me at nagversion@gmail.com- this forum doesnt allow me to add files anymore

Comment: hi ricco ! am using cloudshell

Comment: @naganalytics I see. In your cloud shell terminal can you execute this command `cd && ls | grep "schema.json"`? This will return `schema.json` it it exists in your home directory since based on your screenshot you ran your `bq mk -t` in your home directory. But if the command returned blank, you need to copy over your `schema.json` to your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty table in an existing dataset with a schema definition, enter the following:

```
bq mk \
--table \
--expiration integer \
--description description \
--label key:value, key:value \
project_id:dataset.table \
schema
```

For more info see: [Creating an empty table with a schema definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition)